# Twitter search with urllib2 failing

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I am trying to search Twitter for a given search term with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

link = "https://twitter.com/search?q=stackoverflow%20since%3A2014-11-01%20until%3A2015-11-01&src=typd&vertical=default"
page = urllib2.urlopen(link).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
first = soup.find_all('p')
```

(Replace "stackoverflow" in link with any search term you want.)  However, when I do this (and every time I have tried for the past few days, thinking Twitter might be too bogged down), I get this error:

```
No results.
Twitter may be over capacity or experiencing a momentary hiccup.
```

(HTML in results of BS omitted for simplicity in viewing.)

This code *used* to work for me, but now is not.  Additionally, plugging link directly into a browser gives the correct result and Twitter status shows all is well.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your results.  I believe that Twitter is using this message to discourage people from scraping.  It makes sense since they have taken the time to publish an API for people to access their data, that they discourage scraping.

My advice is to use their API which is documented here: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation

Comment: I am glad it is not just me seeing this result!  That being said, I am currently using the API on a research project to collect tweets on search terms moving forward, but I would like to be able to do a historical analysis of tweets going back several years (possible since this summer when they opened up the advanced search).  I can do this in the web browser, but that is slow and I was hoping for a more automated way.  Am I missing a feature that would let me do this in the API?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used Twitter's API, so I am not sure.